# express and static assets with external resources

Tags: express

I am using Express to serve static assets. Frontend is AngularJS 1.x and I have html5mode enabled. Trying to implement Recaptcha is where I noticed the following in Chrome dev tools:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit“:1

When I click on the function to initiate the Recaptcha process I receive:

> Error: reCaptcha has not been loaded yet.

So far this makes sense to be bacause I noticed the string that the first error is reporting is part of the url path to load Recaptcha from Google.

When I click on the url (api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit“:1) in chrome tools it loads my index.html! Strange!

This has be believing it has something to do with my static asset serving. I have played around with my express server until the cows came home and cannot figure out how to remedy.

Live example:
[http://ninjacape.herokuapp.com](http://ninjacape.herokuapp.com/)

Here is my code and thank you for taking a look!

**index.html**

```
<script src=“https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit“ async defer></script>
```

**express.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');
var app = module.exports.prod = exports.prod = express();

var devAPI = 'http://localhost:1337';

app.use(compression());

app.use(express.static('.tmp'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/.tmp/index.html');
});

var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
app.use('/api', proxy(devAPI));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... I wish I had a better answer however I am just happy I got it to work. Something in the way I am statically serving files is appending any url in index.html to http://localhost:8000. To work around this I took a look at the actual request coming into Express and found the url. Then added logic to redirect that request to the real url.  See commented code below for more info:

```
// Any requests matching /* 
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {

  // Log the original url express is tying to go to
  console.log(req.url);

  // This is the url found from the step above (Where are the extra characters coming from?!)
  var url ='/%E2%80%9Chttps://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit%E2%80%9C'

  // Self explanatory
  if (req.url === url) {

    // Respond by redirecting the request
    res.redirect('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit')

    //End this block and continue
    next();

  } else {

    // If it doesn't match the above url, proceed as normal
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/.tmp/index.html');
  }

});
```